# What's the simplest way to avoid game freezing while calling heavy functions in unity?

Tags: multithreading, unity-game-engine

I'm currently developing a meta tic tac toe AI to play against in Unity. I would like to instantiate particles whenever the player plays a move. However, the particles freeze when the AI's move evaluation function is called. What is the simplest way to make the particles continue to move while the computer is calculating the best move? I've read documentation about unity Job system, but Job structs can't contain reference types which, here is a problem.

```
public void Play (List<Move> moves) {

    int[,] grid = gB.stateGrid;

    Move bestMove = new Move();
    if (firstTurn)
    {
        bestMove.col = 4;
        bestMove.row = 4;
        firstTurn = false;
    }
    else
    {

        foreach (Move m in moves)
        {

            int e = EvalMove(m, level, true, grid, gB.subgridsStates, Mathf.NegativeInfinity, Mathf.Infinity);

            m.value = e;
        }

        int best = moves.Select(x => x.value).Max();
        List<Move> bestMoves = moves.Where(x => x.value == best).ToList();
        bestMove = bestMoves[Random.Range(0, bestMoves.Count - 1)];

    }
    gB.PlaceToken(bestMove);
}
```

The function calculates the bestMove among all possible moves and then asks the game board script to place the corresponding token on the grid.

Comment: Definitely better asked over on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Did you profile your code and checked were the freeze is coming from?
If you are instantiating too many particles, consider doing an object pool to store them and prevent prevent instantiation during runtime.

Also, you can try reducing garbage collection by generating less disposable objects, like "bestMoves".

Then, there is the possibility of running your code on other threads and feeding the result back into the main thread. But beware, because Unity is really picky when working with multiple threads.

Always profile to understand what, exactly, is causing the slowdowns.

Comment: You can run code in other threads using [Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @mcrvaz Because this question is dealing with Unity, it is better to use [Jobs](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/10/22/what-is-a-job-system/) instead.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Just because someone is making a game does not make their question "more appropriate" over on Game Dev. Game Dev used to close-migrate all code questions to Stack Overflow. Given that this is a *code* problem, the question is perfectly suited for Stack Overflow (other issues not withstanding).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Coroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) to do a heavy task and avoid freezing.

Change your method return type to `IEnumerator`

```
IEnumerator Heavy() 
{
    // some real heavy task
    for (int i = 1; i < 10000000; i++) 
    {
        balh();
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
}
```

And simply call it like this:

```
StartCoroutine(Heavy());
```

You just have to run it on a `MonoBehaviour`. that's it.